# iOS Game Center Leaderboard header showing old app name

Tags: ios, swift, game-center-leaderboard

I've integrated a Game Center Leaderboard into my game, but after I started working on it, I decided to change the name of the game. 
I have successfully changed the leaderboard to reflect the name change, but the header/title on the Game Center/Leaderboard view is still showing my old app name.

Google searches suggest it's not ideal to change the bundle ID or project name as this can have other repercussions, so I have just changed the Product Name which has worked in displaying the correct name everywhere else but here.

The only thing still called "SKLab1" is my project. Does anyone know if this is the only way to change this header? 
I haven't been able to find any similar issues that point to where this header is derived from.
Also, apologies as my reputation is too low to post an actual photo! Link below.
Thank you in advance!!

[Leaderboard screen with wrong App name as header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l47NG.png)